# Salesforce1 3rd party OAuth callback

Tags: salesforce1-app, oauth2

I have a **HTML/JavaScript app** that runs (part of a VisualForce page) inside **Salesforce1** that needs to also authenticate with another web server using OAuth.  However, I have not found a way to set the OAuth request callback URL so that the OAuth token can be passed back to my Salesforce1 app page. This needs to work with iOS and Android instances of the Salesforce1 native app.  Is this possible in the current state of Salesforce1?